# Taking a user inputed string and using that string to create an object

Tags: c#, type-conversion

So I've been looking into this for what feel like forever and can not figure out what I'm doing wrong. here are excerpts from my code where I want the string **CashierLOgInNName's** value to be the new Cashier objects name:

```
public class Cashiers
    { 
    public int CashierID;
    public int Password;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;    
        public void SetCashiers(int CashierID, int Password,string FirstName, string LastName )
    {
        this.CashierID = CashierID;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.FirstName=FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

     Console.WriteLine("enter New Log in name");
                          string CashierLOgInNName= Console.ReadLine();

                          Console.WriteLine("enter First Name");
                          string CashierFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.WriteLine("enter Last name");
                          string CashierLastName = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.WriteLine("enter Cashier ID");
                          string f = Console.ReadLine();
                          int NewCashierID = Int32.Parse(f);
                          Console.WriteLine("enter Cashier Password");
                          string g = Console.ReadLine();
                          int NewCashierPWD = Int32.Parse(g);
                          CashierLOgInNName = (Cashiers)Activator.CreateInstance(null, CashierLOgInNName).Unwrap();
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Activator` instead of simply creating the class by `new Cashiers()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a little correction. It will make sure the Cashier's Object **cashierObj** is created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Activators
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter New Log in name");
            string CashierLOgInNName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("enter First Name");
            string CashierFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter Last name");
            string CashierLastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter Cashier ID");
            string f = Console.ReadLine();
            int NewCashierID = Int32.Parse(f);
            Console.WriteLine("enter Cashier Password");
            string g = Console.ReadLine();
            Cashiers cashierObj = (Cashiers)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Cashiers), f, g, CashierFirstName, CashierLastName);
        }
    }
    public class Cashiers
    {
        public string CashierID;
        public string Password;
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public Cashiers(string CashierID, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName)
        {
            this.CashierID = CashierID;
            this.Password = Password;
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.LastName = LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Coming to the next part CashierLOgInNName's value to be the new Cashier objects name. This seems to be tricky and non useful. I suggest there are better alternatives :

1. You can define property `loginName` in Cashiers.
2. You can create a `Dictionary<string, Cashier>` LoginName as key and Cashier Object as value.

But still if you persist there is a way using **CSharpCodeProvider Class** which allows dynamically creating an assembly from source code.
In source code you can write the object name as loginName and then refer that assembly dynamically.

Yet it serves you no purpose as you will not be able to use that object as its name is known to you at run time only. I hope it helps your curiosity.

> “In a time of destruction, create something.” ― Maxine Hong Kingston

Comment: That was a huge help. But forgive me I'm very new to c#, what is the context of using the Dictionary<string, Cashier>?  Is it simply Dictionary<LoginName, Cashier>?

Comment: Dictionary<string, Cashier> is a data structure which denotes that it takes string as key and Cashier object as value. So you can store the Cashier objects in the dictionary also. Anyway long way to go. I suggest you start referencing some books on C#.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation of activator.createinstance and objecthandle.unwrap might be of help.

[Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ObjectHandle.Unwrap Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you but reading that just made.me more confused.  I need more c# practice then I'll come back to that and try again

Comment: Why do you need to use the activator class? are you planning on using .NET remoting?

Comment: This was just a sample project to learn what I'm doing. Activator class was just an attempt. I cant figure out how to have a user enter in a string and then use that string as the name of a new object.  I.E. If I assign a char newName = "SJones"; how to take that variable and say the equivalent of Cashiers SJones = new Cashiers ();

Comment: Once I get that I understand how to save it's attributes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated